# Inserting all rows one by one into a empty table by selecting the rows from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert rows into a empty table by selecting rows from another table both tables containing same columns my query is

```
  declare @name as varchar(50)
  declare @address as varchar(50)
  set @name=(select Name from Test.dbo.T_Sample)
  set @address=(select Address from Test.dbo.T_Sample)
  insert into Sam.dbo.T_Emp(Name,Address)values(@name,@address)
```

My tables are like this

T_Sample

```
 Pk_Id  Name    Address
  1     Sam      Sam
  2      A        A
```

T_Emp

```
 Pk_Id  Name    Address
```

Please help me Thank you

Comment: Answer given by @Juergen is perfect one.

Comment: Yes... He is provided the perfect answer thank you and all for great        co-operation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one statement

```
insert into Sam.dbo.T_Emp (Name, Address) 
select Name, Address from Test.dbo.T_Sample
```

Comment: @SandipPatel: I know how to format a post by now. Please don't edit posts that do not need to be edited. Code format is a matter of taste.